# Unity 2 - Why has the BuildUp method changed?

Tags: unity-container

I am starting to use Unity 2 , having happily used earlier versions. I notice that the IUnityContainer.BuildUP(object obj) method has been removed. Why has this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's here, that's for shure. It's just moved to extension methods.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.unitycontainerextensions_members(v=PandP.20).aspx

Perhaps you don't have

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity
```

In some cases you'll have to add it when migrating from unity 1.2

The following overload is replacement for IUnityContainer.BuildUp(object obj)(actualy BuildUp(T obj)) becouse params ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides are optional
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff662062(v=PandP.20).aspx, so your code should compile without any changes